# SQLite Auto increment field via PHP

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I have this current SQLite table:

```
CREATE TABLE Goal (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Name CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  Image CHAR(256),
  Target INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Priority CHAR(32) NOT NULL
);
```

And am trying to create an integer id via PHP as follows:

```
    $query = 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Goal (Name, Image, Target, Priority) VALUES'; // Query to insert goal-related info into Goal table
    $query .= "('" . $name . "', '" . $image . "', '" . $target . "', '" . $priority . "');"; 
    $addGoalDB -> makeQuery( $query ); 

    $query = 'SELECT last_insert_rowid()';
    $result = $addGoalDB -> makeQuery( $query );
    $id = $result -> fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
    $id = $id['id'];

    $query = 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Users_Goal (Email, id) VALUES'; 
    $query .= "('" . $_SESSION['username'] . "', '" . $id . "');"; 
    $addGoalDB -> makeQuery( $query );
```

But keep getting an undefined index error with

```
$id = $id['id'];
```

I am assuming the query is wrong but cannot find where my problem is. This link: http://alvinalexander.com/android/sqlite-autoincrement-insert-value-primary-key makes it look straightforward but does not work with my code. I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read a column named "`id`". But columns are named after what you have written in the `SELECT` clause, so the actual column name is something like `last_insert_rowid()`.

Give the column a proper name:

```
$query = 'SELECT last_insert_rowid() AS id';
```